# Linq to Entities insert multiple child relationship records for many-to-many relationship using POCO

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I have a database similar to below:

```
Order
===============
OrderID
Description
EmployeeID
...other fields


Product
===============
ProductID
...other fields


OrderProducts
===============
OrderID
ProductID


Employee
===============
EmployeeID
...other fields
```

I'm using Linq to Entities and the **edmx file has been created without the OrderProducts table, as it is just a joining table**. The Products table is a list of static products - I dont need to insert any rows at the moment. The Order table I can insert rows successfully using the following code:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyOrderObject
{
   public int OrderID { get; set; }
   public string OrderDescription { get; set; }
   public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<MyProductObject> ProductsList { get; set; }
   ...other fields
}

[Serializable]
public class MyProductObject
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   ...other fields
}


private static void AddNewOrder(MyOrderObject order)
{
   using (var context = DatabaseHelper.CreateContext())
   {
      var dbOrder = new Order
      {
         OrderID = order.OrderID,
         Description = order.OrderDescription,
         Employee = context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == order.EmployeeID),
      }
      context.AddToOrders(dbOrder);
      context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

**How do I insert into the database my list of child relationship records??**
I've tried:

```
List<int> ProductIDs = order.ProductsList.Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList();
//dbOrder.Products.Attach(context.Products.Where(x => ProductIDs.Contains(x.ProductID)));
//or dbOrder.Products = context.Products.Where(x => ProductIDs.Contains(x.ProductID));
//or dbOrder.Products = context.Products.Contains(ProductIDs);
//or foreach(var p in order.ProductsList)
//   {
//      context.AttachTo("Products", new Product { ProductID = p.ProductID });
//   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change the object type:

```
var dbOrder = new Order
{
   OrderID = order.OrderID,
   Description = order.OrderDescription,
   Employee = context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == order.EmployeeID),
}

//this adds the relationship to the child without adding a new child record - perfect!
foreach(var p in order.ProductsList)
{
   dbOrder.Products.Add(p);
}

context.AddToOrders(dbOrder);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `ProductsList` type to `ICollection`. And make sure it is part of the EDMX mapped model.

```
public class MyOrderObject
{
   public int OrderID { get; set; }
   public string OrderDescription { get; set; }
   public int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
   public ICollection<MyProductObject> ProductsList { get; set; }
   ...other fields
}
```

Then you can add products

```
var products = context.Products.Where(/**/);
foreach(var p in products)
   order.ProductsList.Add(p);
```

Comment: I havent been using EF4 long so I dont understand - why would I want to add the database objects to my POCO object? How does that get the child relationship inserted into the database?

Comment: If I leave it as IEnumerable and change the last line to dbOrder.Products.Add(p); it works! :)

Comment: @JumpingJezza What will add a new `Product`. Don't you want to add a `OrderProduct`?

Comment: `dbOrder.Products.Add(p)` adds an OrderProduct, not a Product - I've tested it. Although it doesnt really seem intuitive.